# Excel calculate value for new category based on other group categories

Tags: excel, pivot

I am getting data from a database that is provided in long format and I need to get ratios from values that are given different categories. E.g. I want the average price based on revenues and quantity sold.

Is there an easy way to calculate this in a pivot once I have the data?
My MWE would look like this

[image]

And I woul like to calculate the new rows with the category price

[image]

One way would probably to do this in MS SQL beforehand, but I am not that skilled with that and I need my colleagues to be able to do this in Excel themselves.

Comment: You can do it with simple formulas. You can do it in Power Query.

Comment: Thx for pointing me into this direction, but I have never worked with Power Query. Would you be so kind to sketch out the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Power Query, you can

- Group the Rows by Year
- From the resultant tables, divide the 1st Value by the 2nd.

Paste the code below into the Advanced Editor; and change the table name in Line 2 to reflect the actual table name of your data.  Then you can explore the "Applied Steps" in the UI to see how the code was generated.

Changing the data table will change the Query results, but you will need to "Refresh" the query.  This can be done form the Ribbon; or you can create a Button on the worksheet.

**M-Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"Year"}, {{"Grouped", each _, type table [Year=number, Category=text, Value=number]}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Price", 
                each Table.Column([Grouped],"Value"){0} / 
                Table.Column([Grouped],"Value"){1})
in
    #"Added Custom"
```

[image]

***Edit:** From your comments, it seems you might have more than just Revenue/Quantity pairs of categories for each year. And I suppose it possible you might have more than a single Revenue/Quantity pair.*

Below is code that will take that into account; breaking the Quantity and Revenue from each year into two columns, then dividing one by the other which would result in a weighted average price for each year:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],

    //needed only if you have blank rows in the table
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Year] <> null)),

    //Group by Year
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Filtered Rows", {"Year"}, {{"Grouped", each _, type table [Year=number, Category=text, Value=number]}}),

    //Extract Revenue and Quantity into two new columns of Lists
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Revenue", each Table.Column(Table.SelectRows([Grouped], each ([Category] = "Revenue")),"Value")),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Quantity", each Table.Column(Table.SelectRows([Grouped], each ([Category] = "Quantity")),"Value")),

    //Sum the value for each List of Revenue and divide by each in the List of Quantity
    //This will result in a weighted average if there is more than one Revenue/Quantity pair in a year
    #"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1", "Price", each List.Sum([Revenue]) / List.Sum([Quantity])),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom2",{"Grouped", "Revenue", "Quantity"}),

    //Some cleanup
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Columns",{{"Year", Int64.Type}, {"Price", Currency.Type}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

Comment: thx. exploring the "applied steps" means playing around with the function to replicate what you just did?

Comment: @MaxM I would just double click on the steps that have a gear wheel, to see what was entered in the UI.

Comment: About the second step that creates the new column. Is there a way to use the category names to do the calculation? Something like : Table.Column([Grouped],"Value"){Revenue} / 
                Table.Column([Grouped],"Value"){Quantity}

Comment: @MaxM Is the problem that you have other categories, and cannot always guarantee the position of `Revenue` and `Quantity`? If so, you can add code to either `Sort` or `Filter` in order to obtain the desired values.

Comment: @MaxM and if you have multiple Revenue/Quantity items for each year, you can combine them (Average, Weighted Average) to obtain a desired results.

Comment: @MaxM Take a look at my edited answer for possibly useful additional code and information.

Comment: Thx a lot, I will have a look. I have other categories, I should not have multiple entries per observation. One way to do it would be to spread the data into columns for quantity and revenue and then caculate the price.